# How to copy a table of data from a website that uses Java application

Tags: java, applet, automation

Situation: I currently log onto a website using my username and password. I then then open a Java Application and click onto a page that displays rows of information i wish to copy. In the top left-hand corner of the screen is a drop down box and selecting each option in this box produces a new table of results.

Task: I am trying to find a way to automate the copy process, rather than manually select each option and copying it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information about the Java application might be helpful in answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, that is do you want to write an applet / extend an existing one (as you're placed tag suggests) or do you simply want to automate a task on your computer to follow along a set of instructions.

For the first scenario, I believe you will need to provide some more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve or even what you tried so far.

And in case you want to create a macro, I would strongly suggest looking at tools like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

---

If I understand correctly, you want to make an application to copy a table from a website for you. Well, this seems to be a simple thing to do, but it might get messy since you're not too familiar with Java.

Basically what I could offer would be to go the most straightforward approach, that is:

- Retrieve the source code (DOM) from the website you need
- Then parse the XML (Just to be sure that you're not confused, Website DOM is actually HTML which is in some sense XML) to XLS using some API for Excel.

Just to be more exact, here's some simple code you can use as a starting point:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://someurl.org");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(url.openStream());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I'm not missing anything, you should be able to get the DOM of a website this way, then just use some XLS api to turn it into XLS file (don't forget that you will need to only parse the table while skipping the rest of the content). You could try [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), though I've never tried it, so don't take my word for granted.

Comment: Im looking to write a script to automoate the process of clicking on options in a drop down menu and saving information as an excel sheet. So far I'm looking into using a Java robot but I am completely new to Java so I just wanted to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/copy_and_paste_in_java) tip, it works fine for me.

Just add the following line below the comment line in file java.policy located in Java\jre6\lib\security.

> // "standard" properties that can be read by anyone permission
>
> java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";

Comment: Please summarize the steps in the article here.  If the link stops working, this answer is not useful.